# How to find a dependency on the assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, nhibernate

I have a solution with about 10 projects, and I recently upgraded to new version on NHibernate, yet when I run solution and get the message: "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference". So some component is looking for old version. I tried removing all references in my project to NH, and re-adding them, deleting all bins etc. I know I can redirect in the config file to a new version, but none of the projects should be depending on the old version. So is there a way to find out which dll is dependent on an old version?

Comment: Try clearing your ASP.NET Temp folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflector can help with this - load the assembly and view the entries under "References".

Comment: Ahhh, how I did not think of that. Anyway none of the dll depend on the old one, according to reflector. Hmmm, there must be something else going on. I inspected every dll in the bin.

Answer (score 5):

There's also [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).